# My app runs very slow after using debugging tools

Tags: visual-c++, heap-corruption, gflags

I was trying to debug a heap corruption issue in our app, and used appverifier, gflags and  _CrtSetDbgFlag to try and track it down.  now i've cleared the gflags, removed our app from app verifier and removed _CrtSetDbgFlag, yet on my computer now the app is horrendously slow (over 15 minutes just to start it up).

It doesn't matter how i run the app, even with visual studio closed and double clicking a release executable i get the same slow behavior.

Can anyone point me to what i may have screwed up on my machine to have this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem for myself by using system restore to go back to before i used gflags.  I notice now that gflags does come with the warning:

*Note   Incorrect use of this tool can degrade system performance or prevent Windows from starting, requiring you to reinstall Windows.*

So i probably should have been more careful.

If anyone has a better way to fix this than system restore, like a list of the registry entries that gflags changes and what they should be by default, that would still be very helpful.